# How is the request getting notified in python rq?

Tags: python, asynchronous, worker

Did I understand http://python-rq.org/ therefore correctly, as it queues jobs in the background, but the request that has triggered the job never gets notified about the result?

Answer (score 0):

I think after finish the job you can callback to notify job have been finished.